# Trigger function from external js script into Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

There is a script that is loaded into my Vue app inside the mounted hook, by this way:

```
let recaptchaScript = document.createElement("script");
recaptchaScript.setAttribute("src", "https://sso.****.com.co/v3/****.main.js");
document.body.append(recaptchaScript);
```

The script is loaded, but there is a function that is injected into the window object.

Currently when I need to use that function, I do this:

```
mounted() {
  let recaptchaScript = document.createElement("script");
  recaptchaScript.setAttribute("src", process.env.VUE_APP_TAPIT_SSO_URL);
  document.body.append(recaptchaScript);
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.ssoApp.configApp(TAPIT_SSO_CONFIG);
    }, 1500);
  });
```

I want to get rid the setTimeOut, but I haven't figured it out yet how to wait for the script executes and inject that object of functions (ssoApp) into the window object without using a timer. Is there any way to do this? I've tried almost everything.

Answer (score 1):

The element should have both `src` *and* an `onload` property. Set the source last, so that everything that can be done synchronously is done before starting to load.

```
mounted() {
  let recaptchaScript = document.createElement("script");
  document.body.append(recaptchaScript);
  recaptchaScript.onload = () => window.ssoApp.configApp(TAPIT_SSO_CONFIG);
  recaptchaScript.src = process.env.VUE_APP_TAPIT_SSO_URL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't work. I choose not to keep trying and I left it the way it was.